# Принцип работы конструкторов сайта

Tags: php, apache

При создании сайта на конструкторе для клиента создается отдельный поддомен с возможностью привязать к нему свой домен. Вопрос как изменяется конфиг апача для каждого пользователя ? И приложение разворачивается отдельно для каждого пользователя, или все-таки есть одно приложение, просто кнему на вход  заходят разные параметры в зависимости от домена ? Спасибо!

Comment: Если все сайты на одном движке, то конечно он может все держать в одной БД и разграничивать по домену. А вообще может быть сделано как угодно, в том числе и с правкой конфигов апача или например выделением отдельных серверов

Comment: @Mike а каким образом создается запись в конфиге для домена ? Каждый раз для каждого клиента перезапускается апач. Я не могу понять принцип работы

Comment: Так директиву ServerName можно и не указывать, тогда данный блок будет работать для произвольных доменов

Comment: Кроме этого есть расширения к апачу, позволяющие брать конфигурацию на лету из базы данных

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444036/apache-virtual-hosts-list-of-server-alias-from-database

Answer (score 0):

Это одно приложение.

Конфиг апача (и не только апача) настроен на работу с wildcard.

Так умеют не только конструкторы, см. "мультисайтовость"